# How to display image size and file name along with image in Python?

Tags: python, image-processing, google-colaboratory

I have a folder with many images I just want to display a 5 random images with size and the file name. so far I can display the images but not sure how to also add in the size and file name.

```
images = [ PIL.Image.open(f) for f in glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg") ]
def imgmap(im):
    if im.mode != 'RGB':
        im = im.convert(mode='RGB')
    return np.fromstring(im.tobytes(), dtype='uint8').reshape((im.size[0], im.size[1], 3))

np_images = [ imgmap(im) for im in images ]

visualize = random.sample(np_images, 5)
for img in visualize:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Do you mean size in like mb because you have the dimensions im.size and names  glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg")

Comment: @kpie yes i mean the mb size of image and the glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg") access all the images in the pics folder but im not sure how to get the specific name of the pic eg, tree.jpg

Comment: have you tried `glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg")[0]` or better yet `files = glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg")` then `files[0]`

Comment: where do you wnat to display it? In console or in `plt` ? And what size do you mean  - image `witdh, height` or file `bytes`. `plt` may need something like `plt.text(..)` or it may need to use `PIL.ImageDraw.text()`

Comment: if you want to display filename with image then you could create list with tuples `(PIL.Image.open(f), f)`. I'm not sure if `PIL.Image` can keep filename after converting. Or check if you can get `im.filename`

Comment: @furas want to display the file size rather then the dimensions.

Comment: @kpie i have now tried the files[0] you recommended and this is good for showing the full path but i just want to take the file name itself to display.

Comment: to get file size you may need `size = os.stat(filename).st_size`

Comment: `plt.text(0, 0,  f"{im.filename} - {size} bytes")` or `plt.title(f"{im.filename} - {size} bytes")`

Comment: you can use `PIL.Image` directly in `plt.imshow()` without converting to `np.array`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get file size

```
size = os.stat(f).st_size
```

to get filename without directory

```
filename = os.path.basename(f)
```

And you should create tuples `(img, filename, size)`

```
images = [ (PIL.Image.open(f).convert('RGB'), 
            os.path.basename(f), 
            os.stat(f).st_size)
                 for f in glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg") ]
```

On my computer `plt.imshow()` can display `PIL.Image` so I don't have to convert to `np.array`. But if you need to convert then you can do it when you create tuple.

```
images = [ (imgmap(PIL.Image.open(f).convert('RGB')),
            os.path.basename(f), 
            os.stat(f).st_size)
                 for f in glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg") ]
```

And later you can get them together

```
visualize = random.sample(images, 5)

for img, name, size in visualize:
    plt.figure()
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.title(f"{name} - {size} bytes")
```

---

**EDIT:**

Code could be more readable

```
def process(path):
    img = imgmap(PIL.Image.open(path).convert('RGB'))
    name = os.path.basename(path)
    size = os.stat(path).st_size
    return (img, name, size)

images = [ process(f) for f in glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg") ]
```

---

Frankly, if you need only 5 images then faster could be first get random filenames and later process only these filenames.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
files = glob("/content/gdrive/pics/*.jpg")
```

then

```
fileNames = [os.path.basename(path) for path in files]
```

and

```
fileSizes = [os.stat(path).st_size for path in files]
```

Now you have arrays that contain your file names and file sizes and hopefully you know what todo from there.

Comment: this give me the correct info but eg with file names it displays all the filenames rather than just the specific images i want to visualize

Comment: @chip you should create list with tuples `(PIL.Image.open(f), f)` or `(PIL.Image.open(f), f, os.stat(f).st_size)` and later `for img, name, size in visualize: ....`

Comment: Not sure where i should make the tuple as if i do it where i declare image then the conversion RGB wont work

Comment: You should look at what a list or tuple is and how to access individual elements of these collections. The idea being that if you have all the things in `aList` then you can get one of the things with `aList[index]` where index is an integer less than the length of the list.

Comment: @chip you could convert directly when you create tuple - see code in my answer. Or you would have to use `np_images = [ (imgmap(im), name, size) for im, name, size in images ]`